# Design db for questions and answers with tags on a blog page

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, xml, architecture, linq-to-xml

Use XML files based or SQL server? Which would be more efficient based on storage size, retrieval and performance?

Comment: Either can be more or less efficient based on how it is implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a big number of blog entries, the database is the way to go. Suppose you want to search a entry with certain text, with the database, you just query using LIKE, in the XML scenario you have to sequentially load the files into memory, do a string search, etc. Painful and slow.

Answer (score 0):

its not exactly blog, 
A webpage where i'm adding a answer question section with tags (similar to stackoverflow but not same), and they will have tags